# Spoofing flash version

Tags: linux, firefox, flash

How do I spoof flash version (make websites think that I have different version that I really have)? I'm using firefox

Comment: Could I ask why you would want to do this?

Comment: Hacker curiosity. There are many ways to spoof browser version and name but I don't know how to do this with flash. No specific use or problem, I just want to learn something new.

Comment: @Connor: Some sites do not [probe the version correctly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/346794/not-detecting-flash-10-worlds-most-widespread-web-video-bug).

Answer (score 2):

There's a whole plethora of ways websites can detect your flash version.

Adobe maintains a ["flash detection kit"](http://www.adobe.com/products/flashplayer/download/detection_kit/) for exactly this purpose.

- Client-side scripting. Uses JavaScript to check for Netscape plugin or ActiveX control. Replace the site's Javascript with your own to spoof this.
- ActionScript based detection. Uses a SWF file to report flash version.
- Server-side detection. Server-side application (ColdFusion, PHP, etc) determines flash version using mime-type information in the HTTP_ACCEPT header. Editing this header would spoof this method.

Comment: Interesting. I upvoted this answer, but obviously I still don't know how to spoof it... but now I at least can learn how version is detected, that's first step. Thanks.

Comment: Aye, I would have gone into more detail, but it's beyond my experience. Glad the answer was of use to you, and thanks for the upvote. =)

Comment: @Phil: that just means you've got something for that "hacker curiosity" to chew on for a while.

Comment: @~quack: Yeah, I'm wondering if any tool or quick 'hack' for achieving this exists or if I would have to use my 'hacker curiosity' and code it, heh ;). BTW I wonder which of those methods of getting version is most common?

Comment: I would assume javascript. Definitely client-side, anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Try Privacy Manager from Ivan Iovation.
You can customize your own flash.

[www.ivanovation.ro/manager](http://www.ivanovation.ro/manager)

[Privacy manager custom flash](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cW6Bg.png)